# How to assign the Kendo UI Scheduler workDayStart Dynamically?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

As of now in navigate event,  we are changing the workDayStart value based on the user selection, however our requirement is the workDayStart  value  has to change when their is an appointment exist in the non working hours. Could some one please help me how achieve this?

Ex: The scheduler workDayStart value 8:00 am, however I have an appointment at 6:00 am. So the scheduler has to automatically adjust the workDayStart as 6:00 am and the similar way need to for workDayEnd.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `setOptions` method, like this:

```
const scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
scheduler.setOptions({
    workDayStart: new Date("2013/1/1 5:00 AM")
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css" />

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2021.2.616/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="scheduler"></div>
  <script>
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
  workDayStart: new Date("2013/1/1 09:00 AM"),
  views: [{type: "day", showWorkHours: true}],
  dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview"
    }
  ],
  navigate: (e) => {
    console.log("navigate e", e);
    
    const scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (e.sender.popup && e.sender.popup.close) {
      e.sender.popup.close();
    }
    
    // Get data from server, mock using setTimeout
    setTimeout(() => { // Callback for data retrieved from the server
        scheduler.setOptions({
        workDayStart: new Date("2013/1/1 5:00 AM")
      });

      scheduler.date(e.date);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The above change needs a refresh to the View, and as well I want to change the workDayStart in DataBound based on the event which I have received.

Comment: Did you try to write this code in the `navigation` event handler? It didn't require a refresh... Added a demo.

Comment: In Scheduler, when we are changing the View/Day it will trigger the navigate event, and it try to fetch the events for the specific date range. The expectation is workDayStart has to set after the completion of event retrieval from Service without refreshing the view.

Comment: You retrieve the events for each day from a server when navigating to that day?

Comment: Yes correct we are hitting server on navigate to get the events, so the navigation day events information will be available after rendering the data.

Comment: I've updated the demo with a way to handle your situation. Basically, in the `navigate` event handler of the scheduler, you can stop the navigation event using `e.preventDefault()`, go to the server and get the data you need and then in the callback of the server call set the date of the scheduler to the navigation date using `scheduler.date(e.date)`.

Comment: In case the snippet gets stuck (it did for me): https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-gtfd77?file=index.html